# Почему цикл прерывается?

Tags: javascript, циклы, while

```
    function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    function numbersCompare(number, answer) {
        if(number==answer){
            alert('Поздравляем, вы угадали!')
        }else if(number==answer+1||number==answer-1 ){
            alert('Вы почти угадали!')
        }else if(number>20){
            alert('Ошибка. Введено некорректное число')
        }else{
            alert('Увы,вы не угадали')
        }               
    }
    var answer = getRandomInRange(1,20);
    var number;
    var i = 0;
    while(true){
    number = prompt('Введите число');
    numbersCompare(number, answer);
    i++;
    if(number=answer){
            break;             
    }
    }
    alert('Ваше количество попыток: ' + i);
```

Comment: Потому что присваивание `number=answer` всегда имеет ненулевое значение и всегда истинно.

Answer (score 0):

Number==answer при вводе числа.

Comment: Стоит ещё добавить проверку на null, что бы кнопочка 'отмена' работала. Ну и не стоит также забывать, что propmpt возвращает строку.

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно распостраненная ошибка у новичков.

Оператор `==` - оператор **сравнения**, а оператор `=` - оператор **присваивания**.

Comment: Это не ошибка, а просто не умение правильно пользоваться операторами и отлаживать код

Comment: @And, это и есть ошибка) Согласно википедии, Ошибка - это "отклонение от правильных действий, поступков"